# Invoking JAX-WS Web service from Camel

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I need to invoke a JAX-WS Web service available on WildFly 8. I've started with a simple example to get started. Here is my Web service:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public class HelloWorld implements Hello{

    @Override
    public String greet(String s) {

        return "Hello "+s;
    }

}
```

The WSDL is available at: http://localhost:8080/DemoWS/HelloWorld?wsdl

Taking a look at the Tomcat-CXF example, I have coded the following route:

```
public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {


    private String uri = "cxf:http://localhost:8080/helloWorld?serviceClass=com.sample.HelloWorld";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from(uri)
            .to("log:input")
            .recipientList(simple("direct:${header.operationName}"));

        from("direct:greet")
            .process(new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                    String id = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                    exchange.getOut().setBody(id);
                }
            })
            .to("log:output");


    }
}
```

By running the above code in a Camel Context, the following error is returned:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route[[From[cxf:http://localhost:8080/helloWorld?serviceClas... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://http://localhost:8080/helloWorld?serviceClass=com.sample.HelloWorld due to: No component found with scheme: cxf
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:177)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:731)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:1803)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1589)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1453)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1421)
    at com.sample.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: cxf://http://localhost:8080/helloWorld?
```

serviceClass=com.sample.HelloWorld due to: No component found with scheme: cxf

It seems I'm not even able to invoke it. Any help ?
Thannks

Comment: You need to add camel-cxf component to your classpath. If you use Maven then add it as a dependency.

Comment: If you are interested to, here is a  [Camel Spring](http://www.mastertheintegration.com/camel/camel-and-web-services/calling-a-jax-ws-web-service-from-camel.html) example which does exactly what you are requesting.

Comment: If you want to invoke the web service from camel route, your need to use to("cxf:xxx") instead of from("cxf:xxx").

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: please explain more about your answer